# List comprehension and str.split() returns lists in list instead of individual strings

Tags: python, list, lambda, list-comprehension

Assume

```
thread_sold = ['white', 'white&blue', 'white&blue', 'white', 'white&yellow', 'purple', 'purple&yellow', 'purple&yellow']
```

I need all items from that list, sometimes separated by & sometimes not. The below function works, but I'd like to know how to do this with list comprehension.

```
def cant_list_comprehend(lst):
    thread_sold_split = []
    for i in lst:
        if "&" in i:
            for x in i.split("&"):
                thread_sold_split.append(x)
        else:
            thread_sold_split.append(i)
    return thread_sold_split

returns ['white', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'white', 'yellow', 'purple', 'purple', 'yellow', 'purple', 'yellow', 'blue', 'blue', 'purple', 'blue', 'white', 'white'...]
```

list comprehension I tried:

```
thread_sold_split_bad = [
    [x for x in y.split("&")] if "&" in y else y for y in thread_sold
]

returns ['white', ['white', 'blue'], ['white', 'blue'], 'white', ['white', 'yellow'], 'purple', ['purple', 'yellow'],...]
```

I'd like to avoid adding named functions to my code if it can be avoided, I'm also interested in solving this with lambda functions, although I'm learning basic stuff at the moment.

Comment: "I'm also interested in solving this with lambda functions" huh? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
thread_sold_split_bad = [
    [x for x in y.split("&")] if "&" in y else y for y in thread_sold
]
```

Your attempt above does not work because you are doing nested list comprehensions instead of a plain comprehension (notice the brackets inside the main brackets). Here is the corrected version:

```
>>> thread_sold_split = [x for y in thread_sold for x in y.split("&")]
>>> print(thread_sold_split)
['white', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'white', 'yellow', 'purple', 'purple', 'yellow', 'purple', 'yellow']
```

Comment: Thanks, I used nested list comprehension to to .strip() elements in a 2d array, it worked there, not sure why it didn't work here, I'll have to dig more into this as I'm still not 100% on list comprehension logic.

transactions_cleaned = [
    [i.strip() for i in transaction] for transaction in daily_transactions_split
]

Comment: Happy to help.
If by "it worked there" you mean it produced a list of lists (i.e a 2D-array) then yes this is what it does.
If you need more help regarding this case, please add a concrete example in the question so that I can help you (or ask a new question if you prefer).

Comment: It was already a 2d array and I had to use nested list to. strip() all elements. Based on that logic I thought that using nested lists for the problem in the question would work, as it would "run append() in the background" or something. I'll play around some more with list comprehension to get better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, [x.split("&") for x in thread_sold])
```

or

```
import itertools

list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x.split("&") for x in thread_sold))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['white', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'white', 'yellow', 'purple', 'purple', 'yellow', 'purple', 'yellow']
```

Comment: **don't use `reduce`  with concatenation to flatten a nested list**